# AVCaptureMetadataOutput scan multiple types

Tags: avfoundation, barcode-scanner

I am new to Xcode (7.2) and Swift and all that.

I had a programmer create me an app as an example for what I want. He is currently unavailable and I cannot find the answer myself.

I want to scan multiple barcode types and I need help integrating that in my code.

This is the code. I can exchange the types and it works fine but I want to support all types at once.

```
let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

if(session.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)){
    session.addOutput(metadataOutput)

    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code]
        //[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode]
    //[AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]
}else{
    scanningNotPossible()
}
```

I assume that I need to redefine something but please help because I cannot figure it out.

Comment: you can try with this repository : https://github.com/maryamfekri/MFCameraManager . it has scan barcode camera and all you have to do is instantiate it in your view controller

Answer (score 1):

This will scan the three types mentioned in the above snippet:

```
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]
```

If you command-click one of the symbols, like `AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code`, you will find other metadata object types you can add to the above array.

Answer (score 1):

But it's a bit slow

```
let metadata = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
metadata.metadataObjectTypes = metadata.availableMetadataObjectTypes
```